# What is a better way of putting a preposition in the sentence below

Tags: prepositions

''You don't start a campfire on/in a damp night.'' I guess it's better to use on because 'on' it sounds right.

Comment: Foreigners should be posting to English Language Learners, not here, as they would realize if they had read the introductory tour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a question of its "sounding right"; or rather, it "sounds right" because **it follows rules.**

Single occasions occurring at a point in a day or a night always use *on*. "On Thursday", "on that day", "on Friday evening", "on a damp night".

*In* means *within,* and is only used with a general "day" or "night" used as a duration: "He did it in one night." Not "He did it in Friday night": that would need *on.*